# left, right, and center alignment with hfill

Tags: horizontal-alignment

this problem is driving me nuts.  I need a line of text formatted as follows:

```
Avian Influenza       Tamiflu          Jan 2, 2011
* This is a random description, note that it spans 
  mult. cols.
* These bullet points--would like to use itemize
  for them.

Chicken pox           DrugXYZ          Feb 3, 1998
* This is another description.
* The "headers" (e.g. DrugXYZ, Avian Influenza) can  
be different, and have different lengths.
```

basically, I want `Avian Influenza` to be left-aligned, `Tamiflu` to be centered, and `Jan 2, 2011` to be right-aligned, such that the disease, dates and drug names in both sets are aligned at the same tabs.  Altogether, the three should span the `textwidth`.

I tried to use tabular, but I want to be able to use `itemize`, etc in the "stuff" portion.

Any ideas??

Comment: Hi Asker, welcome to TeX.stackexchange. I've formatted your samples as code, which you can do by selecting the text and pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: May I suggest you add a complete minimal working example that shows the kind of text you want to align? As it is, the question could be interpreted in a number of different ways.

Comment: @Jake: Indeed - it seems that I saw this rather differently to the intention of the questioner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\MyHeadings[3]{%
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}{#1}  & #2 & #3 \tabularnewline
}
\newcommand\Description[1]{%
  \textbullet & \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{0.97\textwidth}@{}}{#1}\tabularnewline}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.03\textwidth}@{}p{0.42\textwidth}@{}p{0.3\textwidth}@{}>{\raggedleft}p{0.25\textwidth}@{}}
\MyHeadings{Avian Influenza}{Tamiflu}{Jan 2, 2011}
\Description{stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff}
\Description{stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff}
\MyHeadings{Chicken pox}{DrugXYZ}{Feb 3, 1998}
\Description{stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff}
\Description{stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And yet another option: `tabular` is only used for the words requiring alignment, the descriptions are left to an `itemize` environment (customized with the help of `enumitem`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}

\setitemize{leftmargin=*,nolistsep}
\newcommand\MyHeadings[3]{%
  \noindent\begin{tabular}  {@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}p{0.3\textwidth}@{}>{\raggedleft}p{0.25\textwidth}@{}}
    #1 & #2 & #3
\end{tabular}\par
}

\begin{document}

\MyHeadings{Avian Influenza}{Tamiflu}{Jan 2, 2011}
\begin{itemize}
  \item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
  \item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
\end{itemize}
\MyHeadings{Chicken pox}{DrugXYZ}{Feb 3, 1998}
\begin{itemize}
  \item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
  \item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: brilliant..I ended up using the second solution

Answer (score 3):

A simple application of `\hfil` should suffice. For example, wrapping things up in a macro what is wrong with

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\threethings[3]{%
  \noindent #1\hfil #2\hfil #3\\\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}

\threethings{SomeWords1}{SomeWords2}{SomeWords3}
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuf
stuff stuff stuff stuff

\threethings{SomeWords1}{SomeWords2}{SomeWords3}
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuf
stuff stuff stuff stuff
\end{document}
```

---

Based on the comment, a second possible approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\mylength{0.33343\textwidth}
\newcommand\threethings[3]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\mylength}@{}p{\mylength}@{}p{\mylength}@{}}
   \raggedright #1 & \centering #2 & \raggedleft #3
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\threethings{SomeWords1}{SomeWords2}{SomeWords3}
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff

\threethings{SomeWords1}{SomeWords2}{SomeWords3}
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff

\threethings{Short1}{Short2}{Short3}
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuf
stuff stuff stuff stuff
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the note Joseph; I tried something like this, however, the different instances are not properly aligned.   Somewords1 and Somewords3 are properly aligned, but Somewords2 in the two instances are not at the same tab stop....it seems like Somewords2 is actually in the middle of Somewords1 and Somewords3 in that particular line...whereas I need it to be in the middle of the page

Answer (score 3):

The alignment you require can be obtained by saying

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{disease}[3]
  {\par\addvspace{\topsep}\noindent
   \makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\makebox[\textwidth]{#2}\makebox[0pt][r]{#3}
   \par\nobreak
   \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,beginpenalty=10000]}
  {\end{itemize}\addvspace{\topsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{disease}{Avian Influenza}{Tamiflu}{Jan 2, 2011}
\item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff

\item stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
\end{disease}
```

There will be no break between the heading and the first line of the itemized list.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.333\linewidth}@{} >{\centering}X @{}
                  >{\raggedleft}p{0.333\linewidth}@{}}
SomeWords1  & SomeWords2  & SomeWords3\tabularnewline
stuff stuff & stuff stuff & stuff stuf\tabularnewline
stuff stuff & stuff stuff 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: interesting...can I use itemize inside tabularx?...the way I meant to write it, I need the "stuff" part to span all columns, i.e. a single row spanning 3 columns

Comment: sure: but I do not really understand how do you want to use it. Make a complete example, maybe you can extend my one ...